# How to make a public directory restricted in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to restrict non loggedin users from downloading contents, what I have uploaded in a public directory.I am currently working on Laravel 5.2.
So still now what I have done, I just a make a URL which checks the file name and folder name and download the files. In that way, I am hiding my parent folder directory from users. But this is not a good practice because if anybody finds the file URL then they can access it without logging in.

This is my download script:

```
public function getFile(Request $request)
{
          *************
          *************
 $folderFilePath = public_path('my file directory');
 return response()->download($folderFilePath, $filename, []);
}
```

So, is there a way that can restrict downloads from a particular directory for non logged in users in laravel?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep the files in the `storage` directory which is not accessible for users. Then these files will be protected and authenticated users will still be able to download them:

```
if (auth()->check()) { 
    $folderFilePath = storage_path('my file directory');
    return response()->download($folderFilePath, $filename, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [Assigning Middleware To Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware) that direct to the `getFile` method of your controller